# manual drawing of minor tick marks in Matlab plots - length issue

Tags: matlab, plot

I am manually drawing minor tick marks for the axis of my plot using:

```
xg = [xlim(1):XMinorTickDistance:xlim(2)];
xg = repmat(xg,2,1);
yg = [ylim(1) ylim(1)+XMinorTickLength];
yg = repmat(yg',1,size(xg,2));
XMinorTick = plot(xg,yg,'Color',TickColor,'LineWidth',TickLineWidth,'LineStyle','-','Marker','none');
```

it works when I manually select XMinorTickLength with a number. However, I'd like to make it half size of the tick length by doing this:

```
a=get(gca,'TickLength')
XMinorTickLength=a(1)/2;
```

This does not make the minor ticks half size of the major ticks. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
a=get(gca,'TickLength')
XMinorTickLength=a(1)/2;
```

reads the property `TickLength` into the variable `a` and then you create a new variable `XMinorTickLength` containing a/2. Just naming a variable `XMinorTickLength` does not tell matlab to interpret this as a ticklength, it is just some value in your workspace. You need to

```
a=get(gca,'TickLength');
a(1) = a(1)/2;
set(gca,'TickLength',a);
```

The last line writes back the modified `a` to the property `TickLength`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however this is not what I want. I do not want to reduce the length of the major ticks. I want to draw MINOR ticks that are half size of the major ticks. If you read my question again, I am actually drawing some lines as minor ticks and I am defining the length of the minor tick by the variable XMinorTickLength. If works find when I I manually adjust this variable. However, I want it to get its value based on the major ticks of the plot the way I included in my post. But it does not make them half, but much smaller!

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood. From the definition of TickLength in the "Axes Properties" docs the value is a multiplier for the longest visible x,y, or z-annotation line. I think you may need to get your visible axis rect dimensions like `xl = xlim; xlength=xlim(2)-xlim(1)...` and then find the longest of xlength,ylength and zlength (z only for 3d plots). After that multiply the value `a(1)` by the longest axis length to get absolute coords which you can draw. Anyway if it was your problem to get the right tick lengths you can now calc them as well and not draw your own lines perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is many years later but it might help someone. I found myself in this problem and the way I solve it was finding the `XAxis` property `MinorTickValues`

```
ax = gca;
xminorTicks= ax.XAxis.MinorTickValues;
xMinorTickLength = xMinorTicks(2)-xMinorTicks(1);
```

Comment: You might need to add this code just before saving the plot or as the last code. Somehow it can come as empty if it is called before gca calculate the values.